# Duplicate navigation markup with Zurb Foundation

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation 5 in a new company website which I'm in the process of building.

I'm making use of the Off Canvas Menu for smaller/touch screens, and also want to have some more 'traditional' menu for larger screens - the type where you will hover over a main option and get a popup with more menu options.

I've got the menus defined in `ol` tags with submenus in nested `ol`'s.

This is all working... But my question is to do it, I've had to duplicate the markup.

I have the structure defined as follows:

```
<nav>
    <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
        <!-- Full menu markup here -->
    </aside>
    <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
</nav>

<nav id="mainNav" class="row show-for-large-up">
    <!-- Full menu markup also here -->
</nav>
```

I have the following concerns

1. It's bad for SEO to provide the links twice. This is just a concern I don't know if it's really an issue.
2. I've bloated the source - sending everything twice to all requests and allowing the user agents to decide what to show and what to hide. I'm particularly trying to send the minimum markup possible to phones.
3. Maintenance. I'm using ASP.NET MVC so have made use of partial views so I'm only really defining the structure once and injecting it twice; but if I wasn't using this, then there's two points to maintain my menus - this doesn't seem like good practice.

Any thoughts?
Is this correct?

Comment: Foundation's Top-Bar component has this functionality. You may want to consider using it or use it as a guide to modify off-canvas yourself if you are set on using that style.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
<nav class="left-off-canvas-menu hide-for-medium-up">
    <aside >
        <!-- Full menu markup here -->
    </aside>
    <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
</nav>

<nav id="mainNav" class="row show-for-large-up">
    <!-- Full menu markup also here -->
</nav>
```

or 
 class="left-off-canvas-menu hide-for-large-up"
which ever you like 
That should do it I think

Comment: Sorry, but did you read the question?
It's not about how navigation in those different situations work, but about the duplication of content, foundation requires to provide both corresponding with the framework.